# How to load Xib to CollectionView using width constraint in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have collectionView like this

[image]

I'm calling different 3 xib files to cells like this

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "OfficialVehicleHeader", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "OfficialVehicleHeaderCell")
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "OfficialVehicleMedium", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "OfficialVehicleMediumCell")
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "OfficialVehicleBottom", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "OfficialVehicleBottomCell")
```

My collectionView layout code

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

In the xib file i set constraint (leading, trailing, bottom, top as 0) in addition height constraint. The height is running awesome no problem but i don't want to set width constraint. Because there is different between screens

Where did i mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set leading and trailing it will set width according to devices width. But don't forget  to make your collection views constraints to be resizable.

Here is my sample code on how to do it:

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 140).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

layout settings:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 10, height: self.view.frame.height / 3)
```

Cells constraints to be resizable:

```
cell.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cell.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cell.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cell.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I need to set width constraint but i don't want to set. I solve this way

1. Go to xib file and set width constraint
2. Go to size inspector and select that you created width constraint
3. Set identifier for example "myConstraint"
4. Open your cell file and define IBOutlet

   ```
   for constraint in self.containerView.constraints {
     if constraint.identifier == "myConstraint" {
       constraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.70
     }
   }
   containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

I added image that i mentioned

[image]

[image]